# How to "forward" an object property from a pair of individuals to another?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, swrl

Supposing I have:

- some individuals a1 and a2 from class A, b1 and b2 from class B
- an object property "myProperty" from A to A or B to B.
- an object property "otherProperty" from A to B
- a1 :myProperty a2
- a1 :otherProperty b1 and a2 :otherProperty b2

Is there a simple way to infer b1 :myProperty b2?

I am using Protégé with OWL, and I haven't found in the documentation (https://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/object-property-characteristics) any way to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try SWRL? I mean, this look more like an inference where a rule is needed as I doubt OWL property chains would be enough here and you'd need the inverse which isn't allowed in OWL DL

Comment: `myProperty(?a1, ?a2), otherProperty(?a1, ?b1), otherProperty(?a2, ?b2) -> myProperty(?b1, ?b2)` you can add in the Rule view of Protege